# How would I use multiple database clients in an Actix Web Application

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, rust, actix-web

I'm on a project where I need to manage connections to both a MongoDB Instance and a PostgreSQL instance.

My current idea is to make a custom type that will contain an `Arc<Mutex<pgConnection>>` and an `Arc<Mutex<MongoConnection>>` in a struct that itself is within an `Arc` which would be passed to the Actix Web `app_data` initialization function.

e.g.

```rs
// this is pseudo-code, kinda
type DbPoolPG = r2d2::Pool<ConnectionManager<PostgreSQL>>;

// wont be an r2d2 pool, MongoDB official drivers handle pooling automatically
type DbPoolMongo = r2d2::Pool<ConnectionManager<MongoDB>>;

struct DatabseConnections {
    pg: Arc<Mutex<DbPoolPG>>;
    mongo: Arc<Mutex<DbPoolMongo>>;
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    // Create connection pools
    let PostGresPool = r2d2::Pool::builder()
        .build(manager)
        .expect("Failed to create pool.");

    let MongoPool = mongo.create_connection()

    let connections = DatabaseConnections {
        pg: Arc::new(Mutex::new(PostGresPool))
        mongo: Arc::new(Mutex::new(MongoPool))
    }

    // Start HTTP server
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new().app_data(web::Data::new(Arc::new(connections)))
            .resource("/{name}", web::get().to(index))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

The idea seems a bit too simple to actually work though, Does anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

nvm, you can just call `app_data` twice as long as the types are different. then access them by calling the types